# Creating a loader

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

So I'm trying to make a loading screen with react and firebase firestore. Basically, I want to create a loader whenever my app is getting the data from firestore.

EDIT:
For example, I tried doing something like :

```
const [data, setData]=useState([])
const [loader, setLoader]=useState(false)


db.collection('conversations').doc(id).onSnapshot(snap=>{
setData(snap.data())
}).then(()=>{
setLoader(true)
})
```

But this will set the loader to true, but i want to set the loader to true before the data is being access and onces it is retrieved i want to set the loader to false.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The question, as stated, is inappropriate for StackOverflow.  There are many many many ways to accomplish that; any answer would just be an opinion.  StackOverflow etiquette ask that you try to solve a problem on your own,and *if* you have *specific* questions, show your attempt, show your error messages in the most compact minimal way you can.  That way others can benefit from the answers you get as well.

Comment: Well, im fairly new to firebase firestore and I'm just wondering if there is a method to be able to determine when the data from firestore has been fetched

Comment: When the promise returned from the command is resolved. Have you read the documentation?

Comment: Can you please add to the case the documentation you followed, the code you implemented and the error messages you received ?

Comment: I have edited my post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.onSnapShot()` does not do what you think it does - it attaches a *listener* for changes to a document, which will always fire at least once, and then for any further changes - but not necessarily immediately!  It also does NOT return a promise; it returns an unsubscribe function - useful when part of a useEffect hook.

What is happening in *your* code is the listener is attached, then `setLoader(true)` is **immediately** called - because of the Javascript Event Loop, well before the listener function could ever be invoked.

*IF* you intended the `setLoader(true)` to be called *after* data is returned, at a **minimum** you would need:

```
db.collection('conversations').doc(id).onSnapshot(snap=>{
setData(snap.data())
setLoader(true)
})
```

I'll note this by itself does NOT deal with possible errors from the snapshot.

It would more likely be part of a useEffect hook, which will help to unmount the listener when the component is unmounted

```
useEffect(() => {
  return db
  .collection('conversations')
  .doc(id)
  .onSnapshot(snap=>{
    setData(snap.data());
    setLoader(true)
  })
}, []);
```

*IF*, otoh, you just want to get the document once, you'll want to use .get(), which *does* return a promise with a DocumentSnapshot

```
db.collection('conversations').doc(id).get().then(snap=>{
setData(snap.data())
}).then(()=>{
setLoader(true)
})
```

And as requested in comment, for a single fetch:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // no need for a return for a single get
  setLoader(true)
  db
  .collection('conversations')
  .doc(id)
  .get()
  .then(snap=>{
    setData(snap.data());
    setLoader(false);
  })
}, [*whatever state variable will change to start the process*]);
```

...and for the listener (above), take an entirely different approach:

```
const [data, setData]=useState([])
const [loader, setLoader]=useState(true) //DEFAULTS TO LOADING

useEffect(() => {
  return db
  .collection('conversations')
  .doc(id)
  .onSnapshot(snap=>{
    setData(snap.data());
    setLoader(false) //when the data is ready THE FIRST TIME
  })
}, []);
```

There's no need to do anything to set the state to LOADING for any updates by the listener - that will be handled by the State management and setData().  The changes will just show up on a subsequent render each time the listener is called by Firestore

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to set the loader to false once the data has been retrieved from firestore?